# how to merge cells in Excel when one column has numbers with a zero at the begining

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE  ColF  ColG  ColH
C     D     0702  S     4245  X     44
C     D     1105  S     0778  X     83
C     D     0601  S     2242  X     82
```

How can I concatenate a row's cell values without missing the zero to the left?

(in an Excel formula)

Comment: what do you mean, "merge"? concatenate all the values together so you end up with `CD0702S4245X44` in a cell?

Comment: I have try two ways =CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1) and aLso =A1&B1&C1

Comment: either of those formulas removes the zero from the left? i.e. the first line will end up like CD702S4245X44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 0702 is probably not text, it's probably a number formatted as text. Try converting your number to text prior to concatenation, e.g.

```
=A1&B1&text(C1,"0000")&D1&text(e1,"0000")&f1&text(G1,"00")
```

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I TYPED =TEXT(A1,"0000")&B1&C1&D1&E1&F1&G1&H1 and i end up with ED110S8852X54ROX i am expecting ED0110S8852X54ROX

Comment: i formated the cell with a custome value of 0000 so when i only have 3 digits it adds a 0 to the beginning

Comment: If the number is in B1, use the text function on B1, i.e. `=A1&TEXT(B1,"0000")&C1&D1&E1&F1&G1&H1`